# How to enable catch-all email in iRedMail Open Source edition?

Tags: linux, ldap, email-server, openldap

How to create catch-all email alias for domain in iRedMail Open Source edition?

I know that's possible via LDAP and found the following instructions:
http://iredmail.org/wiki/index.php?title=Addition/OpenLDAP/Catch-all

The problem is how exactly to add this parameters via phpLDAPAdmin?

I select "Create new entry here" and choose mailUser type.

Then in step 2 first question is about "RDN" with select box "select RDN attribute".

What should I choose as RDN?
Which fields of the "Create Object" form should be filled?

Unfortunetly there is completely no validation of user input and final errors does not contain explanation what's wrong

Also when I try to import example from iredmail wiki phpldapadmin it gives 
LDIF Import Parse Error
Description:    A valid dn line is required []

dn line is:
dn: mail=@mydomain.eu,ou=Users,domainName=mydomain.eu,o=domains,dc=myserver,dc=pl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the example at the web page given, use a known good tool like `ldapmodify` to add the user:

```
ldapmodify -D admin-dn -w admin-dn-password <<!
dn: mail=@a.cn,ou=Users,domainName=a.cn,o=domains,dc=iredmail,dc=org
changetype: add
accountstatus: active
cn: catch-all
mail: @a.cn
mailForwardingAddress: www@a.cn
mailForwardingAddress: www2@a.cn
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: mailUser
sn: catch-all
uid: catch-all
!
```

Comment: Thanks it works.

The only change is in third line, after dn there should be operation type:
changetype: add.
After adding that line catch-all works OK. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, sorry. Or use `-a` with `ldapmodify` as in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Full working version, only need to change domains and passwords:

```
ldapmodify -D cn=Manager,dc=yourdomain,dc=com -w your-admin-password <<!
dn: mail=@a.cn,ou=Users,domainName=a.cn,o=domains,dc=iredmail,dc=org
changetype: add
accountstatus: active
cn: catch-all
mail: @a.cn
mailForwardingAddress: www@a.cn
mailForwardingAddress: www2@a.cn
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: mailUser
sn: catch-all
uid: catch-all
!
```